# How to automate failover of master in PostgreSQL 9.5 on Windows?

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-replication, postgresql-cluster

I have 4 nodes (version - PostgreSQL 9.5 Beta) in a slot replication set up. Recently the master node, due to less disk space available, PostgreSQL started throwing errors and crashed in the end. As I did not have any failover mechanism in place, the set up could not continue with replication automatically. I have all 4 nodes on Windows Server 2008. I tried looking for a 3rd party manager/tools for the same but found none as repmgr, pgpool-2, handyrep etc work on Linux platforms only. Any ideas on how to automate failover of master or reduce the manual intervention? Secondly, is there an easy and safe way to switch between a master and a slave node?

Comment: Why are you trying to use Windows? That seems like a rather strange choice for a PostgreSQL installation.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Its an old deployment set up as run by our clients since ages. Cannot change that.